# Chefspec how to unit test for update_apt_update without update

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I have the following chef code:

```
apt_update 'Ubuntu apt repo update' do
  subscribes :nothing, 'apt_repository[some-repo]', :immediately
end
```

I'm trying to test with this code:

```
it 'updates apt repo' do
  expect(chef_run).to update_apt_update('Ubuntu apt repo update')
end
```

Which fails with

> expected "apt_update[Ubuntu apt repo update]" with action :update to
>   be in Chef run.
>
> Other apt_update resources: apt_update[Ubuntu apt repo
>   update]

Seems like it's trying to assert my action is update, how do I make it not assume my action?

Comment: wondering whether you have a resource name collision... do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the chefspec, you have already told it to expect **update**_apt_update
so it is expecting an update action from the resource. So, it is not assuming your action and not trying to assert anything. chefspec is pretty simple in the sense that it tries to avoid people do things they don't intend to do.

In the recipe section, please add the action that you are already testing for.

```
apt_update 'Ubuntu apt repo update' do
action :update
subscribes :nothing, 'apt_repository[some-repo]', :immediately
end
```

I always go to these chefspec examples from sethvargo when I need help.

[chefspec examples](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec/tree/master/examples/apt_update/recipes)